# Number of categories , keras

Tags: keras

I have a keras model that classifies images into a number of categories. How do I print the number of categories that my model is classifying the images into?

Comment: improve your post by posting ways/code you have tried to solve your problem

Comment: How many neurons are in the output layer of your model?

Comment: The number of of output neurons determines the number of categories you have..

Answer (score 2):

You can always check the structure of the model using model.summary() in Keras which gives you the information of each and every layer of your model sequentially as shown in the image below.[image]

So in the last layer, which is my output layer, you can see it says output shape is (None, 10), which shows my classifier contains 10 classes or 10 categories. (Do not worry about None it just means batch size).